# How to get x and y coordinate of mouseClick

Tags: winforms, f#, coordinates

I am trying to achieve painting a rectangle around the center of mouseClick position. For that i feel i need to obtain the x and y coordinate as an int.

(This is edited code and `e.X` or `e.Y` is the solutions to this question)

```
  let mouseClick (e: MouseEventArgs) =
  let  x = e.X
  let  y = e.Y
  let coords = [|System.Drawing.Point((x-10),(y-10));
                 System.Drawing.Point((x-10),(y+10));
                 System.Drawing.Point((x+10),(y+10));
                 System.Drawing.Point((x+10),(y-10));
                 System.Drawing.Point((x-10),(y-10))|]
  window.Paint.Add(fun e -> e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, coords ))

window.MouseClick.Add mouseClick
```

I tried using the `e.Location` property that doesn't work which makes sense to some extend since when i print it then it prints "x=(some number) y=(some number)"

Can any one help me obtaining the x and y coordinate as an int?

Comment: Did you tried reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) ? there is `e.X` and `e.Y` (and even if not `e.Location` is of type `Point` which also have `X` and `Y` properties)

Comment: What I don't clearly understand though is that `mouseClick` has type `MouseEventArgs -> Point []` and yet in the last line you're using it as a value of type `Point []`. Don't you forget to apply it some argument ?

Comment: i have edited my code to something else. Sehnsucht. Please bare with me. I went into F# and winforms two days ago. Still trying to figure the basics.

The new code however also causes a problem. This does indeed draw a rectangle at the desired position but I have to minimize and maximize the window in order to get it to refresh the window. But i guess thats a problem for another question.

Comment: ahh window.Refresh() is the solution

Comment: Sehnsucht feel free to make an answer and ofcourse I will give you the credit for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comment, to get mouse position from a [`MouseEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) you simply need to access it's `X` or `Y` properties
*which just reflects the `Location.X` and `Location.Y` properties also available on `e`*

Regarding your edit and your additional comment, I think you've done something wrong by adding a new `Paint` handler with each click and you just need to draw (which probably still requires a `Refresh` at some point though)

```
let mouseClick (e: MouseEventArgs) =
  let  x = e.X
  let  y = e.Y
  let coords = [| System.Drawing.Point(x - 10, y - 10)
                  System.Drawing.Point(x - 10, y + 10)
                  System.Drawing.Point(x + 10, y + 10)
                  System.Drawing.Point(x + 10, y - 10)
                  System.Drawing.Point(x - 10, y - 10) |]

  // maybe use instead of let ?
  let g = window.CreateGraphics()
  g.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, coords)

window.MouseClick.Add mouseClick
```